# Find overall max element to the left of each element in an arrray (not the first max)

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to find the max element to the left of each element but i could write code for only the first max.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]={3,0,0,2,0,4};
        Stack<Integer> st=new Stack<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            while(st.size()>0 && a[st.peek()]<a[i]){
                st.pop();
            }
            if(st.empty()) al.add(a[i]);
            else al.add(a[st.peek()]);

            st.push(i);
        }
        System.out.println(al);
    }
```

Comment: What does "max element to the left of each element" mean? Can you explain the output you're expecting to get?

Comment: For the input 3 0 0 2 0 4 output would be 3 3 3 3 3 4 (I got the solution using an array but here I'm trying to use a stack as Data Structure)
For an element, if there is no max then the current element itself will be in the output array. Ex: for 3 in the array

Comment: What should be the output for 5 0 3 2 0 4?

Comment: 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...Since 5 is the greatest element to the left of each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Stack

```
public static int[] maxLeftElement(int[] A)
{
    final int n = A.length;
    int[] ans = new int[n];

    Stack<Integer> S = new Stack<>();
    S.push(A[0]);

    for (int i = 0;i <  n;i++)
    {   
        if (S.peek() <= A[i]) 
        {
            S.pop();
            S.push(A[i]);
        }
        
        ans[i] = S.peek();
    }

    return ans;
}
```

---

### Efficient Solution

In the above solution, there will be only one element in the stack throughout the execution of the function. Hence, it is quite clear to observe the stack does not offer any benefit whatsoever. Hence, it is better to replace it with a simple `int`.

```
public static int[] maxLeftElement(int[] A)
{
    final int n = A.length;
    int[] ans = new int[n];

    int maxSoFar = A[0];
    for (int i = 0;i <  n;i++)
    {
        maxSoFar = Math.max(maxSoFar,A[i]);
        ans[i] = maxSoFar;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

---

### Intuition

For each `A[i]`, we have to find `max(A[0..i])`, for all the valid *i*. If we think about the possible element, there could be only one max element in `A[0..i]`.

Now, let the max element in `A[0..i]` is `maxSoFar`. We need to find the max left element for `A[i+1]`, which will be `max(A[0...i+1])`. Trivially, `max(A[0..i+1]) = max(A[0...i],A[i+1]) = max(maxSoFar,A[i+1])` which can be solved in constant time.

We already know max left element for `A[0]` will be `A[0]`. So, initially `maxSoFar = A[0]`. Hence, we can simple keep increasing i for all the valid values and compute `max(maxOfFar,A[i])`.

##### Why not stack?

Stack should be used when there is a need to store many elements in a particular order which can help us compute the answer for any `A[i]`. We do not need to keep track of multiple elements at any instant to obtain the answer for any `A[i]` for the problem in question. This rules out the possibility of using stack.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but as mentioned in the previous comment "I got the solution using an array but here I'm trying to use a stack as Data Structure"

Comment: Can you explain the intuition?

Comment: I have added some intuition behind the logic.